# Opening webpage in Ajax and checking statues code

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

I have a code that is supposed to check if a page is loaded and then alert me with a status.
The code for some reason will not work.
I would appreciate it if you can take a look at it and tell me what I did wrong.
Looking foward to a answer!

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;
    if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }else{
    try{
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        }catch(e){
        xmlHttp = false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp){
        alert("Error");
    }
    else{
    return xmlHttp;
    }

}
function process(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "djhgkjshgkjsd.com", true);
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    }
    else{
        setTimeout('process()', 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        if(xmlHttp.status==200){
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
            alert("Hi..."); // This is just to test where my code fails

        }else{
            alert('Something is wrong!');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "will not work."  Where/how does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems here.

The primary one is that you never `send()` the HTTP request.

However, you have some other issues:

- You never call `process`
- You are polling the readyState instead of using a readystatechange event handler
- You are assign a readystatechange handler only when the readyState is already `0` (failed) or `4` (done), so it would never get called
- You have what looks like an absolute URI but

  - The scheme (e.g. `http://`) is missing
  - You will encounter Same Origin Policy restrictions trying to access data about other domains

A cleaned up version of your code might look something like this:

```
// I've removed the code to support IE7 and earlier.
// Those browsers are dead and the approach you were using was
// poor anyway (it prioritised non-standard approaches over
// standard instead of the other way around);

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Warning Cross-Origin request. The server must grant permission
// for your site to access the data using CORS for this to work
xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://example.com", true); 

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
xmlHttp.send();

function handleServerResponse() {
    // Use a local variable. Globals are horrible 
    // and work poorly with event driven programming
    var xmlResponse; 
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            xmlResponse = this.responseXML;
            alert("Variable populated");
        } else {
            alert('Something is wrong!');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! but what do you mean "// Warning Cross-Origin request. The server must grant permission
// for your site to access the data using CORS for this to work"?

Comment: Your site isn't, by default, allowed to instruct the user's browser to get data from another site (which might be private data they only have access to because they are logged into the other site) and make that data available to your JavaScript.

Comment: How can I change that? (If possible). My end goal is to be able to tell if the user has a running server or not. By accessing a page that does not exists I get a browser error or a default server error (That is what I am trying to read).

Comment: There is no way to get information about arbitrary servers from your JavaScript. Do the check from your server instead. You could create a webservice that does it and access that from JS.

Comment: In Ajax there is no way for me to request a webpage as the user?

Comment: Would you like websites you visit to be able to request information from your online banking as you? As I said, unless the site explicitly grants permission, it is not possible.